# How to create canvas class with JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6

I want to create a circle using canvas technology, but to do that I want to make use of ES6 features, and try to make an engine like just drawing and updating stuff with Classes.

I'm having a hard time to draw the circle or know how to go about using Classes. I know how to do it in functional programming, but here I'm not sure how that should be achieved.

I have created somewhat a blueprint, but its far from working I believe.

What can I do to display a circle anywhere on the screen, using Classes for Canvas and the Ufo(circle).

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/mGWVbq?editors=1010

Here is the JS:

```
   /*
    * ------------------------------------------
    * *-----------------------------
    *  Canvas
    * *-----------------------------
    * ------------------------------------------
    */      
      // Set
      // Draw
      // Update
      // Animate
   class Canvas {
      constructor(height, width) {
         this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
           this.c = canvas.getContext('2d');
           canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
           canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      }
   }

   Canvas.prototype.draw = function() {

   }

   Canvas.prototype.animate = function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      new Ufo()
   }




   /*
    * ------------------------------------------
    * *-----------------------------
    *  UFO
    * *-----------------------------
    * ------------------------------------------
    */
   class Ufo {
      constructor(x, y, velocity) {
         this.x = x,
         this.y = y,
         this.velocity = {
            x: 3,
            y: 3
         }
      }
   }

   Ufo.prototype.draw = function() {
      c.save()
      c.beginPath()
      c.arc(this.x, this.x, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
      c.fillStyle = red;
      c.fill()
      c.closePath()
      c.restore()
   }

   Ufo.prototype.update = function() {
      Ufo.draw() 
   }

 new Canvas(animate)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) Unfortunately, this question is far too broad for SO's format. SO is for **specific** problems, not general advice for class design, or code review.

Comment: Its about implementing Canvas with Classes. I never talked about code review. Also, it's specific problem for 'class design' as well. Otherwise, all of the other questions people asked would be also wrong.

Comment: Why would you limit yourself using classes in the first place. JS is much more that that.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to learn on how to do a small game like a UFO that can move and shot, but for that, I need to render it. I want to make it proper, and get all the concepts right. So I though using classes for the canvas was the way to go. Looking at this book it seems like having Canvas class is the way to go, but I'm not there yet, right now just want to create something very simple to strenghten my knoweldge. So was wondering, how do I go about it with ES6 using CLasses. http://eloquentjavascript.net/17_canvas.html#canvasdisplay

Comment: But then, I'm still learning so wondering how to make this work. Later will want to add more functionality to it and get some more concepts while I read the book and learn more. WOuld be good to ahve a place and try these things out visually like on canvas. Was learning theory now practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code. 
This is the corrected code:

```js
'use strict';

/* UFO*/
   class Ufo {
      constructor() {
         this.x = 77,
         this.y = 77,
         this.velocity = {
            x: 3,
            y: 3
         }
      }
      
      draw(c) {
         c.save()
         c.beginPath()
         c.arc(this.x, this.x, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
         c.fillStyle = "red";
         c.fill()
         c.closePath()
         c.restore()
      }
      
      update(c) {
         this.draw(c)
      }
   }

/* Canvas*/  

   class CanvasDisplay {
      constructor() {
         this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
     this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
         this.stageConfig = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
         };         
         this.canvas.width = this.stageConfig.width;
         this.canvas.height = this.stageConfig.height;
         this.Ufo = new Ufo();
      }
      
      animate() {
         this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.stageConfig.width, this.stageConfig.height);
         this.Ufo.update(this.ctx)
      }
   }


let canvasDisplay = new CanvasDisplay();
canvasDisplay.animate();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I hope you'll find this useful.

Comment: Thank you! So I wasn't that far! Did a few mistakes here and there. How come you passed a 'c' in the draw and  update method in the UFO? Later, or rather now, I will want to add movement in the update method, so will need to catch event. I'd assume I can catch the keys on the canvas and if one key corresponds, add velocity to the x and y cordinates. But how come it has a c inside? And how come inside animate, ufo has  in the update this.ctx? shoudn't the ufo update itself or something? Still learning.

Comment: In order to draw() you need to use the canvas context. save(), beginPath(), arc() etc are methods of the context. You have to pass the context (c) as an argument, otherwise you'll get undefined.

Comment: Shoudn't that be ctx? If this is ` this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');` ?

Comment: Aurelian Spodarec: inside the class CanvasDisplay you declared the this.canvas property whose's context is this.ctx. You never declared a ctx variable.

Comment: Inside the draw() you are using the context, and the context is not a global variable, so you need to pass the context (c) as an argument

Comment: Sort of get it. I suppose because the context gets updated to we need to access it, something like that I guess. Would you help me on this part of the project as well please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136080/how-to-add-event-listener-and-move-an-object-in-canvas-using-es6-classes?noredirect=1#comment91227338_52136080

Really trying to wrap my head around this by building something, and then reflex it and re-do it to gain better understanding.