# How to add event listener and move an object in canvas using ES6 Classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas, es6-class

I'm creating a small game where you can move a star/ufo. I'm having a hard time to figure out how I should make it move. With functional programming its easy, but how do we go about doing this with ES6 utlizing classes? Do we need to bind or something? I suppose my logic is also somewhat wrong.

How can I make the circle move?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/mGWVbq?editors=0010

```js
'use strict';
/*
 * ------------------------------------------
 * *-----------------------------
 *  User Event
 * *-----------------------------
 * ------------------------------------------
 */
class UserEvent {
  constructor(canvasBody) {
    this.UP_ARROW = 38 || 87,
      this.RIGHT_ARROW = 39 || 68,
      this.DOWN_ARROW = 37 || 83,
      this.LEFT_ARROW = 40 || 65,
      this.keys = []

    canvasBody.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      this.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    });

    canvasBody.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      this.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    });
  }

  checkKey(key) {
    return this.keys[key];
  }

  ufoMove() {
    this.canvasBody.checkKey(this.UP_ARROW)
    this.canvasBody.checkKey(this.RIGHT_ARROW)
    this.canvasBodycheckKey(this.DOWN_ARROW)
    this.canvasBody.checkKey(this.LEFT_ARROW)
    console.log(this.canvasBody.leftArrow = this.checkKey(this.LEFT_ARROW))

    if (this.UP_ARROW) {
      this.x += this.x * this.velocity.x
    }
  }
}


/*
 * ------------------------------------------
 * *-----------------------------
 *  UFO
 * *-----------------------------
 * ------------------------------------------
 */
class Ufo {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x,
      this.y = y,
      this.velocity = {
        x: 3,
        y: 3
      }
  }

  draw(c) {
    c.save()
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    c.fillStyle = "#fff";
    c.shadowColor = "#e3eaef";
    c.shadowBlur = 20;
    c.fill()
    c.closePath()
    c.restore()
  }

  update(c) {
    this.draw(c)
    // Get the keys first
    this.EventUser.ufoMove(this.c);
    //    this.x = this.x + this.velocity.x;
    // }
  }
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------
 * *-----------------------------
 *  Canvas
 * *-----------------------------
 * ------------------------------------------
 */
class CanvasDisplay {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.stageConfig = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    };
    this.canvas.width = this.stageConfig.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.stageConfig.height;

    this.backgroundGradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, this.canvas.height);
    this.backgroundGradient.addColorStop(0, '#171e26');
    this.backgroundGradient.addColorStop(1, '#3f586b');

    this.Ufo = new Ufo(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2);
    this.UserEvent = new UserEvent(document.body);
  }

  animate() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundGradient;
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    this.Ufo.update(this.ctx)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  }
}

let canvasDisplay = new CanvasDisplay();
canvasDisplay.animate();
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. That snippet is pretty cool. Yeah, but problem is I'm not sure how to fix that. I'm still learning Classes and I'm new to this, and not sure what to do. In my head this should be work because I called the new ufo move in the animate, so that should take whatever is up right. Though it doesn't work, and not sure whats wrong with that. I suppose its not that far but was reading eloquent JS and trying to put in this to practice now, but having bit trouble to fully understand this. Do you know what's wrong with that? On why is that undefined? I tried few things and nothign worked :/

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to access the upper class that's named 'EventUser' and use it inside the Ufo update method. I know that 'this' is linking to the wrong thingy, but how would you do it otherwise? I need to access the ufoMove method from the class 'EventUser' inside the class 'Ufo' inside its method 'update'. I did declare new EventUser and new Ufo in the canvas display, so I would believe it should work because of that reason, but can't figure out how to make that work. I tried everything, and nothing works. I must be getting the logic/concept wrong or something?

Comment: Yeah, it's my code. I just learned about classes and now trying to build it. I sort of understand it but this is putting it in practice. There is only so much I can do if I keep on readin and reading without actually doing. So I'm trying to add the movement now to it. I managed to draw this, I understand ish how it works, but enxt challenge is to add functionality to it. I know how to do it in functional programming, already did that, but I want to figure this out and then reflec on it and re-do it again to get better understanding, need to finish this first for maximum understanding though.

Comment: Because that's how one learn, by doing, and I got a mistake here and there, but if I can get help and solve it, and reflext on it, then I'll learn, instead of re-learning the same thing over and over again. I read eloquent JS and some tuts on YT and started to do this. I'm learning this for few days so I might forget but I know that this is a way to go about this and learn it, otherwise I will be always reading theory without practice, and you learn best by doing and actually checking if one understands it properly, or just understands theory. Which is also important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this code (a little bit different of what you had in mind)

```js
let keys = {ArrowUp:false,ArrowDown:false,ArrowLeft:false,ArrowRight:false};

         window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
            keys[e.code] = true;
         });

         window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
            keys[e.code] = false;
         });

  /*UFO*/
   class Ufo {
      constructor(x, y) {
         this.x = x,
         this.y = y,
         this.velocity = {
            x: 3,
            y: 3
         }
      }
      
      draw(c) {
         c.save()
         c.beginPath()
         c.arc(this.x, this.y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
         c.fillStyle = "#fff";
         c.shadowColor = "#e3eaef";
         c.shadowBlur = 20;
         c.fill()
         c.closePath()
         c.restore()
      }
      
      update(c) {
        if(keys.ArrowUp){this.y -= this.velocity.y;}
        if(keys.ArrowDown){this.y += this.velocity.y;}
        if(keys.ArrowLeft){this.x -= this.velocity.x;}
        if(keys.ArrowRight){this.x += this.velocity.x;}
        this.draw(c);
      }
   }

   /* Canvas*/  
   class CanvasDisplay {
      constructor() {
         this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
       this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');       
         this.cw = this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
         this.ch = this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
         
         this.ufo = new Ufo(this.cw / 2, this.ch / 2);
       
         this.ctx.fillStyle = this.grd();
      }
      
      grd(){
         let grd = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, this.ch);
         grd.addColorStop(0, '#171e26');
         grd.addColorStop(1, '#3f586b');
         return grd;
      }
      
       animate() {
         window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
         this.ctx.fillRect(0,0,this.cw,this.ch);
         this.ufo.update(this.ctx);
      }
   }

   let canv= new CanvasDisplay();

   canv.animate();
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

lease take a look at this code: